# Scale axis tick labels for coordinates plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, fits

I am working with VLBI data (Very Long Baseline Interferometry, like one that was used to make a recently trended black hole shadow image). 
I am plotting an image which is taken from a FITS file. By the means of a WCS transformation, it is converted from pixels to physical units, i.e. degrees. Also, I have put a central pixel to (0,0) in physical units.

It looks nice when plotted. But I want to label axes in mas(milliarcseconds) because the imaged area on the sky is really small. 
So instead of 0deg0'0.001" or 0.001" I would like to see 1 as the tick label.

[image: Now, x-axis looks like this, units are arcseconds]
[image: I want it to look like this. Units are milliarcseconds, i.e. 0.001 of an arcsecond]

Here is a basic code to open a figure:
    
    `wcs = WCS(i[0].header).celestial  # where i is a FITS object
    wcs.wcs.crval = [0,0]  # to remove absolute coordinates of a source
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = wcs)
    ra, dec  = ax.coords[0], ax.coords[1]`

- I have tried playing with

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(format_func))
```

but it seems to be not implemented yet for axis which are not 'scalar'.
 => raise NotImplementedError()  # figure out how to swap out formatter

- Changing axis mode to 'scalar', i.e.

```
ra.set_coord_type('scalar')
```

breaks the locator, I believe.
=> all tick labels are overlapping at 0 of the x axis.

- Addind scale did not work at all (supposing I did everything correctly)

```
ax.ticklabel_format(useoffset = 1000, style = 'sci')
```

=> no changes

Are there any other means of converting axis labels for coordinate data to milliarcseconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some efforts, I have found the root of the issue.
For VLBI maps, the axes should be defined as offsets, not RA and DEC, i.e.

```
w.wcs.ctype = [ 'XOFFSET' , 'YOFFSET' ]
```

This solves the whole issue and no major tweaking is required anymore.

Comment: Your approach helped me a bit, but I still get problems on the scales. Do you have any idea what is it wrong? Please check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64480066/astropy-coordinate-conversion-problem-of-a-fits-file

Comment: the link brings me to nowhere. But we may discuss the issue here. And please upvote if you find it useful.

Comment: Now the link is available.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a not very elegant way of doing this, maybe it will work in this case. I use labels for the axis that are strings instead of int.

```
x_values = [0.000, -0.003, -0.006]
labels = []
for value in x_values:
    labels.append(str(convert_to_mas(value)))

ax.set_xticks(x_values)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

This is just the general idea, but you will have to adapt it to your code. I could be more specific if you added a small reproducible example. :)